# Add action to button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table wich displays data in different levels (Parent, Child, Grandson) when I click on the parent it displays new rows related to the child level and if I click on child it displays a third level as the grandson with more rows.

What I want to do is to add a button on each record with the "+" symbol so when I click it I'll see the second level and switch that button from the parent to another with the "-" symbol, to simulate the expand and collapse functionality, I want to do this for also for the child level.

Now the columns expand or collapse if I click on a row but I want to do this if I click on the buttons that I want to add.

Here's my code:

```
    $('.drillDown tr td:last-child, .drillDown tr th:last-child').hide();

$('.drillDown tr td:first-child, .drillDown tr th:first-child').dblclick(function(){
    $('.drillDown tr td:last-child, .drillDown tr th:last-child').show();

})


    $('table.drillDown').each(function() {

        var $table = $(this);
        $table.find('.parent').dblclick(function() {
            console.log( "*****Click on Parent" );
            $(this).nextUntil('.parent', ".child").toggle("fast"); 
            $(this).nextUntil('.parent', ".grandson").hide("fast");
        });

        $table.find('.child').dblclick(function() {
            console.log( "*****Click on child" );
            $(this).nextUntil('.child', ".grandson").toggle("fast"); 

        });

        var $childRows = $table.find('tbody tr').not('.parent').hide();
        $table.find('button.hide').dblclick(function() {
            $childRows.hide();

        });
        $table.find('button.show').dblclick(function() {
            console.log("*****Click on Child");
            $childRows.filter('.child').show();
        });
        $table.find('tr.child').dblclick(function(){
            $(this).nextUntil('.child').show()
        });

    });
```

And also my fiddle with the complete example

https://jsfiddle.net/ny6qcxtd/2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
changed with following fiddle
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ntcnxxb/)

Comment: your logic is going wrong when you are click in children symbol. It displays - sign in place of + sign. Steps to get issue 1) click on parent symbol. 2) then after click on child symbol. 3)then after clik on parent symbol so all row is collapsed. but after that again you click on parent symbol, child symbol displays - insted of +. check your jsfiddle.

Comment: @LaljiNakum Thanks for your time, I wanted to use some fancy buttons but this works perfect for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can add action to your button with .click(handler) function in jquery

EX.

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

where `target` is your button's id.

Comment: Please , tick it as a right answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 2):

Look at these code, it's simple design with Higher performance.
may be it will help you,

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">

            <table class="table table condensed drillDown">

                <thead>

                    <!--SUB HEADER 2-->
                    <tr style="background-color: #E3E3E3">

                        <!--SALES-->
                        <th></th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Categories</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">LW $</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">LW</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">L4 W</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">L13 W</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">L52 W</th>

                    </tr>


                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr class="parent" style="cursor:pointer">  
<td style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px;font-size: 20px;">+ </td>  

                        <td>33 D33 GIRLS DRESS </td>

                        <td>$1,564.90</td>
                        <td>1.5%</td>
                        <td>1.7%</td>
                        <td>6.4%</td>
                        <td>1.1%</td>


                    </tr> 

                    <tr class="child" style="background-color: #D8E8B7">
<td style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px; font-size: 20px;">+</td>
                        <td>05 D05 MOVIES</td>

                        <td>$897.56</td>
                        <td>2.2%</td>
                        <td>1.34%</td>
                        <td>4.7%</td>
                        <td>8.9%</td>


                    </tr>

                   <tr class="grandson" style="background-color: #D8E8FF">
<td style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px; font-size: 20px;">+</td>
                        <td>05 D05 MOVIES</td>

                        <td>$897.56</td>
                        <td>2.2%</td>
                        <td>1.34%</td>
                        <td>4.7%</td>
                        <td>8.9%</td>


                    </tr>

                    <tr class="child" style="background-color: #D8E8B7">
<td style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px; font-size: 20px;">+</td>
                        <td>06 D06 BATTERIES</td>

                        <td>$2,673.99</td>
                        <td>1.3%</td>
                        <td>0.7%</td>
                        <td>7.5%</td>
                        <td>3.6%</td>

                    </tr> 

                    <tr class="parent" style="cursor:pointer">
<td style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px; font-size: 20px;">+</td>
                        <td>19 D19 HOME DECOR</td>

                        <td>$1,673.99</td>
                        <td>3.3%</td>
                        <td>5.7%</td>
                        <td>2.5%</td>
                        <td>3.6%</td>


                    </tr>

                    <tr class="child" style="background-color: #D8E8B7">
<td style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px; font-size: 20px;">+</td>
                        <td>34 D34 LDS WVN TOPS</td>

                        <td>$2,673.99</td>
                        <td>1.3%</td>
                        <td>0.7%</td>
                        <td>7.5%</td>
                        <td>3.6%</td>

                    </tr> 

                    <tr class="child" style="background-color: #D8E8B7">
<td style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px; font-size: 20px;">+</td>
                        <td>72 D72 AUDIO HARDWARE</td>

                        <td>$2,673.99</td>
                        <td>1.3%</td>
                        <td>0.7%</td>
                        <td>7.5%</td>
                        <td>3.6%</td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr class="child" style="background-color: #D8E8B7">
<td style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px; font-size: 20px;">+</td>
                        <td>72 D72 UNASSIGNED</td>

                        <td>$2,673.99</td>
                        <td>1.3%</td>
                        <td>0.7%</td>
                        <td>7.5%</td>
                        <td>3.6%</td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr class="child" style="background-color: #D8E8B7">
<td style="font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px; font-size: 20px;">+</td>
                        <td>87 D87 UNLOCKED PHONES</td>

                        <td>$2,673.99</td>
                        <td>1.3%</td>
                        <td>0.7%</td>
                        <td>7.5%</td>
                        <td>3.6%</td>

                    </tr>  
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

</div>
```

now you can bind simple onclick function with your GUID, and add such class which replace your + with -, when user opens any row.
so, there is no need to bind buttons,
if you need any further help, ping me in comments.

Comment: Thanks for your time and disposition for further help, its awsome!
:)

Answer (score 1):

## Maybe you could use something like this:

```
$(".classOfButton").click(function() {
                $(".classOfWhatYouWantToExpand").fadeToggle("slow", "linear")
            });
```

So on the click of your button use the jQuery .fadeToggle() function. Just pay attention to what your goal is, and use classes or id's appropriately.

[fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) 
[jQuery .click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: using Bharat's code below should get you to a position where you can easily associate the click functions of those '+'  sections he made with the fadeToggle() function. That comes with a nice animation too.

Comment: Thanks for your time :)

Comment: i just made it to look like Microsoft portals, here it just demo version but i have full softer code...

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#target").click(function() { 
   alert("click event"); 
});
$("#target").submit(function() { 
   alert("submit event"); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time :)

This help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

simply you can bind a button click function, see below code.

for exa.

```
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

for your code it looks like,

```
$( "#target" ).on( "click", function() {
 console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```